# Flutter: Minimising Firestore read/write operations

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am new to Flutter and mobile development in general and currently trying to wrap my head around certain database principles. I am building an note-taking app which uses Firestore for storing note data to the cloud. Users first need to register an account and log in, after which they are able to view and store notes to the cloud. The way I initially designed this was by using `StreamProvider` connected to the Firestore instance to update the user's list of notes after they add a note to their list.

After some reflection and worries that my app would be 'read' intensive, I realised that what I am trying to build does not require the notes to be constantly fetched from the server, as the data is private to them and should only be fetched by the user that creates it. My solution is instead of creating notes and listening to changes on the Firestore server to update the list, when a user creates a new note, a function should run and update the Firestore server as well as a local nosql database, removing the need for a read operation on the server after writing to it. This would allow me to have a local duplicate copy of the Firestore server and to periodically update it with write operations when needed. The only read operation would be on the app's startup to fetch a copy of the Firestore server.

My questions are:

1. Is storing a local version of the Firestore server a viable solution to minimise the number of read operations in my app, or am I overcomplicating things?
2. The `StreamProvider` allowed me to easily access data relating to the user, notes, etc throughout the app using `Provider.of<Model>(Context)`. How can I easily access this data regardless of where I am in the app?
3. Given that my Firestore database structure for accessing notes is `users/{user.id}/notes/{note.id}/note` , how can I get a snapshot of the current logged in user ID and all the child fields in a single request (i.e. all the user's notes in `users/{user.id}/notes` and user data under `users/{user.id}/`)

Comment: We are you performing *a read operation on the server after writing to it*? There's generally no reason to do that since the data is already in your app. You may be adding unneceeary complexity to your app by also using a local database as Firebase can pretty much handle the whole thing.

Comment: I am performing a read operation after updating the Firestore server with data, i.e. after creating a note, Firestore immediately fetches the updated list of notes (with the new note added) using ```StreamBuilder``` (from what I understand at least). This makes my app quite read intensive as each note retrieved with ```StreamBuilder``` counts as a read for Firestore. The idea behind using a local DB would be to minimise the use of Firestore to reduce read ops and thus costs, but also to make the app fully available offline during long periods of time.

Comment: That process is very confusing; if you have a list of notes showing in your app, and a new note is added, why would you re-read all of the notes? At most you should be using a child added event which would only present the most currently added note.